# cakephp inside form how to get input value

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm using cakephp 1.3,I want to create a link with to params ( id and nbr) to call function in controller but the problem is I can't get the input value inside my form..

here my code:

```
<tr>
    <td width="25%"> <?php echo $value['StocksCour']['module_formation']; ?> </td>
    <td width="25%"> <?php echo $value['StocksCour']['nb_stock']; ?> </td>
    <td width="25%">
        <?php
        echo $form->create('StocksCour'); 
        echo $bouton->add('-', array('id'=>'subtsract', 'div'=>false));  
        echo $v->input('nbr_edit',array(
            'id'=>'nbr_edit',
            'label'=>false,
            'default'=> $value['StocksCour']['nb_stock'], 
            'div'=>false,
            'style'=>'width:30px;'
        ));
        echo $bouton->add('+', array('id'=>'add', 'div'=>false)); 

        echo $v->input('id_formation',array(
            'type'=>'hidden',
            'name'=>'id_formation',
            'id'=>'id_formation',
            'value'=>$value['StocksCour']['nom_formation']
        ));
        ?>  
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <?php
        echo $v->link(
            'Valider',
            array(
                'controller'=> 'Sessions',
                'action'=>'saveChange',           
                $value['StocksCour']['id_formation'] ,
                $this->data['StocksCour']['nbr_edit']
            ),
            array(
                'image'=>'tick.gif',
                'class'=>'button small',
                'post'
            )
        );
        ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is she have to get the new 'nb_edit' after change ..